# Se recarga la pestaña cuando intento activar la cámara para escanear QR con la librería ngx-scanner-qrcode en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pug, qr

Estoy implementando en mi proyecto de angular, una librería para escanear códigos QR mediante la cámara del ordenador. El problema es que cada vez que precioso el botón para escanear la cámara me pide permisos, le doy aceptar, se enciende la cámara y luego se recarga el navegador. A que crees que se pueda deber? gracias.

Enlace de la librería https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scanner-qrcode

Mi código pug:

```
button((click)="escanear(action, 'start')") Escanear
ngx-scanner-qrcode(#action="scanner", [config]="config", (event)="onEvent($event)")
```

Mi código typescript de angular

```
public config: ScannerQRCodeConfig = {
    fps: 1, 
    isAuto: false,
    isBeep: true,
    constraints: {
      audio: false,
      video: {
        width: {
          width: 200, 
          height: 200
        }
      }
    } 
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onEvent(e: ScannerQRCodeResult[]): void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  escanear(action: any, fn: string){
    action[fn]().subscribe(console.log, alert);
  }
```

Comment: Podrías proporcionar un [example]?

Comment: Este es un ejemplo del mismo creador de la libreria https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-scanner-qrcode?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts